alternative to SageConv to support edge weights in PyTorch Geometric
I want to use graphSAGE to find abnormal nodes. I want to use edge weights for my graphs which is not supported in graphSAGE using (PYG) PyTorch Geometric library. If I use GraphConv instead of SageConv, which supports edge weight for the input graph, then is the function of GraphConv similar to SageConv? And is GraphConv totally different from GCNConv?
